# Can I make a batch file that sets up a https proxy for IE without showing command line or window?

Tags: batch-file, proxy

I would like to create a batch file that sets the `HTTPS proxy`, or respectively any proxy for IE. And i would like it without any window, command line or log. Just in plain background. Please excuse my low knowledge of Windows, due to me preferring rather Mac and Ubuntu. I would like the setup Adequately on a Windows 7.

Comment: This might be better suited for superuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`without any window, command line or log`  - the only option left is a pure magic..
To automatize the proxy settings you can edit the [registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819961?wa=wsignin1.0) :

```
reg ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v "ProxyServer" /d "http://ProxyServername:80"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
@echo off
```

hides the command prompt

good luck

Comment: Not true; it just prevents the commands in the batch script from being shown during execution. The window will still be shown.